# Increment Dictionary value after find Dictionary item by Key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Dictionary defined as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, double> collection = new Dictionary<string, double>();
```

Now i want to fine specific element by it's `Key`, if this `Key` is missing i want to add new `Key`, `Value`, if exist i want to increment the `Value`:

```
string str;
if (!collection.ContainsKey(str))
    _collection.Add(str, 0);
else
{
    KeyValuePair<string, double> item = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == str);
    // Here i want to update my Value.
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't use FirstOrDefault to look up an item in a dictionary. Use the index directly : collection[str]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx) to update it with the incremented value:

```
if (!collection.ContainsKey(str))
    collection.Add(str, 0);
else
{
    collection[str]++;
}
```

That works because it's the same as:

```
collection[str] = collection[str] + 1;
```

MSDN:

> You can also use the Item property to add new elements by setting the
>   value of a key that does not exist in the Dictionary.
>   When you set the property value, **if the key is in the
>   Dictionary, the value associated with that key is
>   replaced by the assigned value**. If the key is not in the
>   Dictionary, the key and value are added to the
>   dictionary.

---

If you have another collection of `KeyValuePair<string, double>` as commented and you want to update the dictionary with those values if the key exists or add them if it doesn't exist:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, double> pair in otherCollection)
{
    if (!collection.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
        collection.Add(pair.Key, 0);
    else
    {
        collection[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK that's fine but if i want to loop through my collection and update my value with specific value ?

Comment: @berrywer: This is a totally different question, I think you need to create another post for that.

Comment: @berrywer: _what_ collection? You are using `_collection` and `collection` in your code which is confusing.

Comment: @berrywer: i have edited my answer to show you how to loop another collection to update this dictionary.

Comment: Instead of using ++ i want to insert different value and in this way i cannot do that (only if i want to increment the exist value) - any suggestions how to do that ?

Comment: Why [pair.Key] = pair.Value ? my Key is string and Value is double and when i try to [pair.Value] = some double value i have this error: cannot convert from 'double' to 'string'

Comment: @berrywer: i don't understand what you are trying to do, maybe you should really post another question as Ivan has already suggested since this is a different issue. This question is about incrementing a dictionary's value if the key exists, otherwise add it.

Comment: **Inefficient solution.** Your code searches in the dictionary 3 times for existing values, while 2 is enough. First time in the if statement, second time for getting the value to increment, third time when updating the value.  See @IvanStoev's answer for correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why people continue posting code with that dictionary anti-pattern `if (dic.ContansKey(key)) value = dic[key]`.  The most efficient and correct way is like this

```
string str;
double value;
if (!_collection.TryGetValue(str, out value))
{
    // set the initial value
    _collection.Add(str, 0);
}
else
{
    // update the existing value
    value++;    
    _collection[str] = value;
}
```

Note that comments are included just for the example, normally it would be just

```
if (!_collection.TryGetValue(str, out value))
    _collection.Add(str, 0);
else
    _collection[str] = value + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`_collection[str]` will give you the value corresponding to the key specified in the `[]` so,`_collection[str]++` will increment the value corresponds to the key by `1`

You have to change the else part only as like the following:

```
string str;
if (!_collection.ContainsKey(str))
    _collection.Add(str, 0);
else
{
   _collection[str]++;
}
```

Comment: Inefficient to use ContainsKey.

Answer (score 0):

With C# 7.0, the easiest and most efficient way of doing this is:

```
_collection.TryGetValue(str, out double value);
_collection[str] = value++;
```